# How to exclude directions from bash script search that lists number of non blank non comment // lines?

Tags: bash

I have this  bash script code.  It gives me the number of lines that are not blank and not comment (//).  I pieced this together from two other questions on your site.

I wanted to optionally have the ability to exclude directories from the recursion, and when I applied that, things did not seem to work.  Very new to bash. This is the base version without any exclusion ideas, wondering if someone could recommend the changes to exclude directions from the recursion:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.js' -o -name *.qml \) -exec cat {} \; | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*\/\//d' | wc -l
```

The following seems to work to exclude one directory:

find . -path './ui/applications/browser/unittests/qml' -prune -o ( -name '*.js' -o -name *.qml ) -exec cat {} \; | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*///d' | wc -l

But when I extend to multiple directories to exclude, errors:

```
find . -path './ui/applications/browser/unittests/qml' -prune -o './tools/demoBrowser/content' -prune -o \( -name '*.js' -o -name *.qml \) -exec cat {} \; | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*\/\//d' | wc -l
```

Do you see what I am doing wrong with syntax?  with the latter attempt, I get message:

'find:  paths must precede expression '

Comment: btw, does the tag "windows" make sense??

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways for command find to ignore files/directories. here I am giving you a couple of find options.

- using `-regex pattern`, then you have the power of regex to exclude any paths you want.
- using `-path` and `-prune` to ignore directories. in man page there is a nice example for it.

I cannot give concrete command/script. since I don't know your dir-structure and what kind of file/dir you want to ignore.

anyway you really should read man page of `find` for detail.

from find man page:

> `-path pattern`
>
> > File name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do
> >                 not treat ‘/’ or ‘.’ specially; so, for example,
> >                           `find . -path "./sr*sc"`
> >                 will print an entry for a directory called ‘./src/misc’ (if one
> >                 exists).  To ignore a whole directory tree, use `-prune` rather
> >                 than checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip the
> >                 directory ‘src/emacs’ and all files and directories under it,
> >                 and print the names of the other files found, do something like
> >                 this:
> >                           `find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print`
> >                 Note that the pattern match test applies to the whole file name,
> >                 starting from one of the start points named on the command line.
> >                 It would only make sense to use an absolute path name here if
> >                 the relevant start point is also an absolute path.  This means
> >                 that this command will never match anything:
> >                           `find bar -path /foo/bar/myfile -print`
> >                 The predicate `-path` is also supported by HP-UX find and will be
> >                 in a forthcoming version of the POSIX standard.

Comment: I tried the following using -path and -prune and it does not seem to remove the directory specified from consideration. I did not see the example in the man page for find or purge you were describing.

find . -path './/ui/applications/browser/unittests/qml' -prune -o \( -name '*.js' -o -name *.qml \) -exec cat {} \; | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*\/\//d' | wc -l

Comment: ah, I was missing the -path statement in the second exclude: 

    find . -path './ui/applications/browser/unittests/qml' -prune -o -path './tools/demoBrowser/content' -prune -o \( -name '*.js' -o -name *.qml \) -exec cat {} \; | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*\/\//d' | wc -l